# How to bootstrap in R

Tags: r

I obtained the returns of the RUT index running a backtest in R in Quantstrat.
Now I would like to create a bootstrap of the returns but I do not know how to do it.
I know that the boot() function needs data, statistic, and number of bootstrap repetitions.
In data I think I can add "returns" ( see code below )
But I do not know how to compute "statistic". 
Can someone help?

Please refer to the code below:

```
library(devtools)
library(quantmod)
library(quantstrat)
library(TTR)
library(png)
library(IKTrading)
install_github("braverock/blotter")
install_github("braverock/quantstrat")
install_github('IlyaKipnis/IKTrading')


initdate <- "2010-01-01"
from <- "2012-01-01" #start of backtest
to <- "2017-31-12" #end of backtest
n<- 30

Sys.setenv(TZ= "GMT") #Set up environment for timestamps

currency("USD") #Set up environment for currency to be used

symbols <- c("RUT") #symbols used in our backtest
getSymbols("^RUT",src="yahoo", from="2012-01-01", to="2017-12-31", periodicity="daily")


wma <-  WMA(Cl(RUT), n=4, wts=c(1:4))
wmamaxt <-  rollmaxr(wma, n, fill = NA)
wmamint <- - rollmaxr(- wma, n, fill = NA)
CNOwma <- function (RUT) {(wma - wmamint) / (wmamaxt - wmamint)}

stock(symbols, currency = "USD", multiplier = 1) #tells quanstrat what instruments present and what currency to use

tradesize <-10000 #default trade size
initeq <- 100000 #default initial equity in our portfolio

strategy.st <- portfolio.st <- account.st <- "firststrat" #naming strategy, portfolio and account

#removes old portfolio and strategy from environment
rm.strat(portfolio.st)
rm.strat(strategy.st) 

#initialize portfolio, account, orders and strategy objects
initPortf(portfolio.st, symbols = symbols, initDate = initdate, currency = "USD")

initAcct(account.st, portfolios = portfolio.st, initDate = initdate, currency = "USD", initEq = initeq)

initOrders(portfolio.st, initDate = initdate)
strategy(strategy.st, store=TRUE)

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
              name = 'SMA',
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=100),
              label = 'SMA100')

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
              name = 'SMA',
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=30),
              label = 'SMA30')

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
              name = 'SMA',
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=15),
              label = 'SMA15')

add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns=c("SMA15", "SMA30")),
           relationship = "lt",
           label = "Exitlong")

add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns=c("SMA15", "SMA100")),
           relationship = "gt",
           label = "Enterlong")



add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "Exitlong", sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = "all", ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "long", replace = FALSE,
                          prefer = "Open"),
         type = "exit")



add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "Enterlong", sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = 1, ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "long", replace = FALSE,
                          prefer = "Open", osFUN = IKTrading::osMaxDollar,
                          tradeSize = tradesize, maxSize = tradesize),
         type = "enter")

out <- applyStrategy(strategy = strategy.st, portfolios = portfolio.st)
updatePortf(portfolio.st)
daterange <- time(getPortfolio(portfolio.st)$summary)[-1]

updateAcct(account.st, daterange)
updateEndEq(account.st)

for(symbol in symbols){

  chart.Posn(Portfolio = portfolio.st, Symbol = symbol, 
             TA= c("add_SMA(n=15, col='blue')", "add_SMA(n=30, col='red')", "add_SMA(n=100, col='green')"))
} # in “symbol” add “RUT” or “IXIC”


final_acct <- getAccount(account.st)
end_eq <- final_acct$summary$End.Eq

returns <- Return.calculate(end_eq, method="log")
library(boot)
 boot(returns, k=1, R=1000)
Error in boot(returns, k = 1, R = 1000) : 
  l'argomento "statistic"  non è specificato e non ha un valore predefinito
```

Comment: I removed tags for the bootstrap CSS framework and bootstrapping an application.  You are interested in the statistical approach called bootstrapping.  Please read the descriptions of the tags you add.  I'm not sure if there is one for bootstrapping but you can check.

Comment: What is it that you mean by k=1?  You need to tell boot what statistic to calculate on the samples.

Comment: I has read that you have to insert a function that produces the k statistics to be bootstrapped (k=1 if bootstrapping a single statistic)... k=1 was just a guess... The fact is that I do not know how to compute the statistic as I am asked to write a function that combined with the data produces the test statistic of interest, but my data already is a vector of the test statistic of interest that I am interested in and I do not need to combine it with a function to obtain it. I hope I was clear enough

Comment: For example you might put "mean" or "sd".  In boot are you sampling from that vector?  Maybe you want to start by bootstrapping the mean.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are doing because you have a lot of code not related to the question.  But it might be that Return.calculate is what you want.

Comment: I want to bootstrap the vector of returns sampling from that vector. Putting the mean is a good idea, thank you. Unfortunately it seems not to work:
boot(returns, mean, R=1000)
Error in mean.default(coredata(x), ...) : 
  'trim' must be numeric of length one

Comment: `Error: ‘getSymbols.google’ is defunct.` Your code doesn't run, please revise it. (When I changed to "yahoo" it also didn't run, different error.)

Comment: Not knowing anything about your vector I can't really comment. But try getting the mean from the vector and see if there is a problem with the result there.

Comment: @RuiBarradas fixed, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Elin the vector contains returns and the date in which the return was registered. If I do the mean of the vector I get NA as a result. This may be due to the fact that the first 32 elements of the vectors are NA.

Comment: Well you need to set na.rm=TRUE.

Comment: Now the error is `Error in chart.Posn [...etc...] no transactions/positions to chart`. Also, `end_eq` is an object of class `"xts" "zoo"` with length 1. You cannot bootstrap a dataset with **just one data point**.

Comment: @Elin where do I have to set it?
Like this: boot( returns, mean(returns, na.rm=TRUE),R=1000) ?

Comment: @RuiBarradas : now it works for me. Vector returns contains around 1500 data points. But I keep having the issue with boot

Comment: You are right, now it works. What is the statistic you want to bootstrap? That is missing from the question. It should be a function of `end_eq`, I believe.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I want to bootstrap the daily returns contained in the vector called "returns".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following does what you want.

```
library(boot)

boot_returns <- function(data, indices){
  d <- data[indices]
  Return.calculate(d, method="log")
}

bret <- boot(end_eq, boot_returns, R=1000)

dim(bret$t)
bretMeans <- colMeans(bret$t, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you Rui Barradas for you helpful answer. I have a question, I think that in data I have to insert my returns, but what do I need to insert as "indices"?

Comment: @Pietro Nothing, function `boot` will do it for you. And in `data` you will pass `end_eq`, not `returns`, this is what the function outputs. Check out `bret$t0`, `identical(bret$t0, returns)` outputs `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of `boot()` [`based on Chapter 5, Page 196 in` [`ISLR`]](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) to calculate bootstrapped mean of a column in a dataframe. (`R version 3.3.0`). The `boot()` function needs `data`, a `function` that calculates a statistic of interest and `number of bootstraps 'R'`. Here, the `function` has to have two inputs i.e. `data` and an `index` to iterate.

**Calculate mean using boot()**

```
# Import libaries
library(boot)

# Create sample dataframe
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(1000, sd=10)
y <- rnorm(1000, sd=1)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

# Create function to pass to boot()
calc_mean = function(data, index){
  mean_x <- mean(df$x[index]) 
  return(mean_x)
}

boot(df$x, calc_mean, R=1000)
```

[image]

**Compare above bootstrap mean with that calculated directly with `mean()`**

```
mean(df$x)
```

[image]